# Angular ui router - Share views between states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to create a web app where I have an index.html page with three views: header, content and footer.

I'd like the header and footer to be consistent between pages but at the same time not be part of the index.html file.

I'd also like the content view to change depending on the url I've gone to.

Here is my current solution

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <header ui-view="header"></header>
    <main ui-view="content"></main>
    <footer ui-view="footer"></footer>
</body>
```

**app.js**

```
$stateProvider
    .state('my-app', {
        abstract: true,
        views: {
            'header': {
                templateUrl: 'partials/shared/header.html',
                controller: "UserController"
            },
            'footer': {
                templateUrl: 'partials/shared/footer.html'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('my-app.home', {
        url: "/",
        views: {
            'content': {
                templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
                controller: 'HomeController'
            }
        }
    })
```

When I load the page "/" it shows the header and footer as having loaded correctly and I can see them on the page, but the main content is missing.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I managed to figure it out.

I had to get the view in my child state to point to the view in the root state explicitly.

To do that I had to point to 'content@'.

Fixed code:

**app.js**

```
$stateProvider
    .state('my-app', {
        abstract: true,
        views: {
            'header': {
                templateUrl: 'partials/shared/header.html',
                controller: "UserController"
            },
            'footer': {
                templateUrl: 'partials/shared/footer.html'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('my-app.home', {
        url: "/",
        views: {
            'content@': {
                templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
                controller: 'HomeController'
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a parent for my-app.home :

```
.state('my-app.home', {
    parent: 'my-app',
    url: "/",
    views: {
        'content': {
            templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not quite. The header and footer are loading fine when I load the my-app.home state, it's just the 'content' view isnt being displayed. I can see in the console that it's loading the file, just not actually injecting it into the index.html.

Comment: You are rigth. I don't show errors in your code. Perhaps, try to replace main by a div

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('my-app', {
        abstract: true,
        views: {
            'header': {
                templateUrl: 'partials/shared/header.html',
                controller: "UserController"
            },
            'content': {                 
               template: '<ui-view/>',
             },
            'footer': {
                templateUrl: 'partials/shared/footer.html'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('my-app.home', {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
    })
```